# Sphinx in yii2 creates error: "Undefined index: Index"

Tags: indexing, yii2, full-text-search, sphinx

I have installed Sphinx on Ubuntu 14.04 and I can use it from the command line like "search TestQueryTitle".
From within yii2 I can also successfully do this (to get all article IDs):

```
    $querySP = new \yii\sphinx\Query();
    $rowsSP = $querySP->from('article')
        ->select('id')
        ->all();
```

But I get the error "Undefined index: Index" when I try to do a fulltext search like this:

```
   $querySP = new \yii\sphinx\Query();
   $rowsSP = $querySP->from('article')
        ->match('TestQueryTitle')
        ->all();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In your code there is a type missing ) in select('id'

Comment: thanks. just corrected the typo..

Comment: Same here. Any suggestions?